# memcpy and shared memory struct

Tags: c, shared-memory, memcpy

I have a struct in a shared memory segment and I'm trying to reach a 2d array inside my struct using memcpy.

```
struct shared_mem_struct{

        int proc_id;
        int flag[21];
        int turn;
        char bounded_buffer[5][200];

};
```

I'm trying to access the bounded_buffer with memcpy, but I keep getting garbage back.

```
memcpy(shared_mem->bounded_buffer[z], "empty", sizeof(shared_mem));
```

I've read the documentation of memcpy, but I'm coming up empty on a solution that works. I've also tried:

```
memcpy(shared_mem->bounded_buffer[z], "empty", sizeof(shared_mem->bounded_buffer[index));
```

I'm able to read and write in all of the forks, so accessing the shared memory isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are doing something wrong.

```
memcpy(shared_mem->bounded_buffer[z], "empty", sizeof(shared_mem));
```

should be

```
memcpy(shared_mem->bounded_buffer[z], "empty", strlen("empty")+1);
```

Because it is not the size of buffer bytes of characters you want to copy rather you want to copy those letters from `"empty"`. That's why the length should be `1` is added to the length.

In your case, you were accessing memory that was beyond the string literal. That was [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: That solved it. Much appreciated and you've cleared up some confusion.

Comment: @shatter.: Good then. All the very best.